# jquery not finding img src of current li

Tags: jquery

I'm erroneously trying to find the img src attribute of an element.  Here is my code and I'll explain expected behavior.

```
  $('.flex-control-nav').ready(function(){

    $('.flex-control-nav').find('li').each(function(){
      console.log($('img').attr('src'));
    });

  });
```

html is like this:

```
  <ol class="flex-control-nav flex-control-thumbs">
  <li><img src="//example.com/s/files/1/0519/6401/products/c7b83f87-4c30-4d47-a32b-3a4e7e645607_400x400.jpg?v=1546474879" class="flex-active" draggable="false"></li>
  <li><img src="//example.com/s/files/1/0519/6401/products/blahblah_400x400.jpg?v=1546643593" draggable="false"></li>
  <li><img src="//example.com/s/files/1/0519/6401/products/blahblah2-Hat_400x400.jpg?v=1546643586" draggable="false"></li>
  </ol>
```

By finding li in flex-control-nav I would expect it to console.log each img IN THAT li but instead it's logging each img the page originally finds.  What would be the correct way to get the img src attrigute of each li?

Comment: `$(this).find('img').attr('src')`

Comment: You attach ready to the document, not an element

Answer (score 2, accepted):

jQuery doesn't automatically scope selectors to the current element in `.each()`, you need to do that yourself. `this` contains the current element of the iteration.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('.flex-control-nav').find('li').each(function() {
    console.log($(this).find('img').attr('src'));
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ol class="flex-control-nav flex-control-thumbs">
  <li><img src="//example.com/s/files/1/0519/6401/products/c7b83f87-4c30-4d47-a32b-3a4e7e645607_400x400.jpg?v=1546474879" class="flex-active" draggable="false"></li>
  <li><img src="//example.com/s/files/1/0519/6401/products/blahblah_400x400.jpg?v=1546643593" draggable="false"></li>
  <li><img src="//example.com/s/files/1/0519/6401/products/blahblah2-Hat_400x400.jpg?v=1546643586" draggable="false"></li>
</ol>
```

Answer (score 1):

To search in a limited scope, select that scope and use `find()`:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {

  $('.flex-control-nav').find('li').each(function() {
    console.log($(this).find('img').attr('src'));
  });

});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ol class="flex-control-nav flex-control-thumbs">
  <li><img src="//example.com/s/files/1/0519/6401/products/c7b83f87-4c30-4d47-a32b-3a4e7e645607_400x400.jpg?v=1546474879" class="flex-active" draggable="false"></li>
  <li><img src="//example.com/s/files/1/0519/6401/products/blahblah_400x400.jpg?v=1546643593" draggable="false"></li>
  <li><img src="//example.com/s/files/1/0519/6401/products/blahblah2-Hat_400x400.jpg?v=1546643586" draggable="false"></li>
</ol>
```

Answer (score 0):

You are not passing the current element to your anonymous function in the each loop:

```
$('.flex-control-nav').find('li').each(function(index, element){
  console.log($('img', element).attr('src'));
});
```